# tsql looping issue, duplicate records are being inserted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TagID as INT;

DECLARE tag_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT tagname FROM #temptag  
FOR READ ONLY
  OPEN tag_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @tag
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN  

               IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE TagName=@tag) 
                    BEGIN
                       SELECT @TagID = TagID FROM Tag WHERE TagName = @tag    
                       Insert into NoteTags(NoteID,TagID) values (@NoteID,@TagID)
                   END 
               ELSE
                   BEGIN

                       INSERT INTO Tag
                       SELECT @tag FROM #temptag 
                       SELECT @TagID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                       Insert into NoteTags(NoteID,TagID) values (@NoteID,@TagID) 

                   END

                FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @tag
            END


           CLOSE  tag_cursor   
           DEALLOCATE tag_cursor
```

I am passing parameters to procedure using XML, I have created a temporary table and stored all values from XML into it. And then I have written Cursor to check if value already exists in the table or not.

If value is not available records will be inserted.

Problem: If I send two values from XML say IND, USA  which doesn't exist in my table, duplicate records are being inserted in the table.

Can anyone tell what mistake I made with my code.

After modifying..

```
   BEGIN

                       INSERT INTO Tag(TagName) values(@tag);

                       SELECT @TagID = IDENT_CURRENT('Tag');
                       Insert into NoteTags(NoteID,TagID) values (@NoteID,@TagID) 

                   END
```

Comment: It is because if the data exist you still insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is causing your problem:-

```
    INSERT INTO Tag
    SELECT @tag FROM #temptag
```

You already have the value of @tag - but the `select` is duplicating it for every row in `#temptag` so you end up with duplicate rows in Tag

remove the `select` and change the `insert` to:-

```
    insert into tag (TagName) values (@tag)
```

Comment: I am getting duplicates even after changing from SELECT to INSERT

Comment: which table ends up with duplicates?  does #temptag start out with multiple rows for the same TagName when loaded from your xml?

Comment: Tag table has duplicate values, Yes my xml has multiple rows, but I read each row at a time and insert into temporary table #Temptag, and then I have cursor on #tempTag which takes each value and checks if it exists in Tag table or not.

Comment: When i changed statement to Insert instead of select, 

If my input is Krish and Krish1, surprisingly after change Krish is inserted only once but krish1 is inserted with duplicate records

Comment: with the change I suggest - the only way Tag can end up with multiple rows is if #temptag has multiple rows for the same tagname. When is #temptag getting cleared?  May be worth checking its contents before enumerating your cursor to make sure the xml has loaded the way you expect.

Comment: In my temporary table there are no duplicate values. I am dropping my temporary table each time I run the procedure

Comment: The only way the duplicates can be created is if they exist in the temp table - or if the loop is being executed multiple times without the temp table being cleared. `INSERT INTO Tag(TagName) values(@tag);` cannot create multiple rows - and its the only `insert` statement (involving the tag table) in your code... put a `print` inside your loop and check the value of @tag for each enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a set based answer to avoid the cursor:-

```
insert into tag (tagname)
select tt.tagname
from #temptag tt
where not exists(
    select *
    from tag t
    where t.tagname=tt.tagname
)

insert into notetags (noteid,tagid)
select @noteid,t.tagid
from tag t
where exists(
    select *
    from #temptag tt
    where tt.tagname=t.tagname
)
and not exists(
    select *
    from notetags nt
    where nt.noteid=@noteid
    and nt.tagid=t.tagid
)
```

There is no clue in your code where @noteid gets set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better idea would to not use the cursor. How about doing an outer join between the temporary table and the Tag table and only do an insert where the tag entry is null?

I find it pretty rare that you'd ever need to use a cursor.

Comment: I dint get that idea, I will give a try